# two UserControls, one page, need to notify each other of updates

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I've got a user control thats used twice on the same page, each have the ability to be updated (a dropdown list gets a new item) and I'm not sure what might be the best way to handle this.

One concern - this is an older system (~4+ years, datasets, .net2) and it is amazingly brittle.  I did manage to have it run on 3.5 with no problems, but I've had a few run-ins with the javascript validation (~300 lines per page) throwing up all over the place when I change/add/modify controls in the parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't even need most of it, I forgot to mention it was vb, so I put this in the user control...

```
Public Event UpdateListings As EventHandler

Public Function SomethingToDo

    'doing some cool stuff ...not really

    RaiseEvent UpdateListings(Me, EventArgs.Empty)

    Return result
End Function
```

then on the code behind on the parent page

```
Protected Sub UpdateStuff(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles userControl1.UpdateListings, userControl2.UpdateListings
    userControl1.BindStuff()
    userControl2.BindStuff()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Add an event to your user control.

```
    public event EventHandler MyEvent;

    protected void OnMyEvent(EventArgs e)
    {
        if(MyEvent != null)
        {
            MyEvent(this, e);
        }
    }

    protected void AddOptionAdded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnMyEvent(EventArgs.Empty);
    }
```

Then in your page you can subscribe to both controls event.

```
    protected  void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebUserControl1.MyEvent += OnMyEventHander;
        WebUserControl2.MyEvent += OnMyEventHander;
    }

    protected void OnMyEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Notify the other controls that something changed.
    }
```

Then in your page's event handler you can do whatever you need to do to update the other control.  Calling a method, etc.

You can also go as far as creating your own delegate and EventArgs classes to pass additional custom data that may be needed.

Comment: ok that didn't work, see my "answer" to my own question (I tried to post that stuff to a comment ... formatting fail)